# nuxt-leaflet problem with server side rendering (window is not defined)

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, nuxt.js, undefined, server-side-rendering

i've been working on a ssr nuxt project n wanted to add nuxt-leaflet but apparently there's a window reference in nuxt-leaflet module that causes an (window not defined) error while server side rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because `nuxt-leaflet` use window object, you should render your component on client-side

```xml
<client-side>
   <Component/>
</client-side>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).